# Concurrent files uploads on IIS 10 never succeed and freeze the user session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis, asyncfileupload

**Configuration:**

Windows Server 2016 4Gb ram, ASP.NET MVC 5, IIS-10, Max upload size per request:30M

**Problem:**

When uploading 5 image files of 500Ko asynchronously, the user session freezes and the uploads never succeed. If I try to reach another page of the website from the same browser, it hangs. From another browser, I can reach any pages of the website. The user session hangs until I restart the website in the IIS.

As soon as I restart the website, the all uploads resume uploading and succeed as it would normally do and all the pages of the website are again reachable by the user.

**What I tried so far:**

1. Up to 4 images of 500Ko, it is working fine. 
   If I take images of 5M each instead, it works for 1 upload but not 2 concurrent uploads.
2. If I run the website on my local computer, it is working fine.

Any ideas what could lead to such a situation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the exact same issue and Brando's answer helped me find the solution.

Try adding `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]` to the line above your controller processing your image uploads.

Like so:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class ImagesController : Controller
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may face the session lock issue. I suggest you could try to debugdiag to capture the dump file and analysis the dump file to find out the reason.

debugdiag download link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924

Steps:
1. Open the debugdiag and select performance.
[image]

2. Go next and select HTTP response times
   [image]
3. Click next and add the url with timeout value
   [image]
4. Click next and click add dump target and select target type to web application pool and select the right application pool
   [image]
5. Click next and select full dump and click next 
   [image]
6. Type in the dump rule name and click next
   [image]

More details, you could refer to below article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h